# A supposedly “stoppable” service is not stoppable

Tags: windows-10, command-line, drivers, touchscreen

I'm trying to stop the service `mshidkmdf`, but it won't stop despite the fact it's STOPPABLE. I'm able to stop the driver from device manager (the device stack is `\Driver\mshidkmdf` and the description is `HID-compliant touch screen`). When I run `sc query mshidkmdf`, I get:

```
SERVICE_NAME: mshidkmdf
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

which implies that the service is `STOPPABLE`. But, when I run `sc stop mshidkmdf`, I get:

```
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1052: 

The requested control is not valid for this service.
```

and when I run `net stop mshidkmdf`, I get:

```
The requested pause, continue, or stop is not valid for this service.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2191.
```

I know the service is running because a) my touch screen is running and b) when I run `sc start mshidkmdf`, I get:

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

An instance of the service is already running.
```

My goal is to stop the device (my touch screen) that is run by the driver through the command line, but as far as I understand the driver and the service are the same thing.

Comment: A service and driver are NEVER the same thing.  At least to windows.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas That's not really true. A driver is a type of service, a driver is a service of type SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, SERVICE_FILESYSTEM_DRIVER, etc. What we commonly call services are actually non-driver services, of types SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS, etc. The GUI hides the fact that drivers are type of service, but at the [API level](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicea) it becomes quite clear that they are.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Driver services live in the kernel. Non-driver services do not live in the kernel. That's [Microsoft's official terminology](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/about-services): "The service control manager (SCM) maintains a database of installed services and driver services..." I am only talking about NT/2000/XP/Vista/7/8/10 here; the SCM component doesn't exist in 9x/Me.

Answer (score 1):

This service is for Windows Touch, and Windows indeed refuses to disable it.

You might do better to disable the device itself, as explained in the
Microsoft article
[Enable and disable your touchscreen in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028019/windows-enable-and-disable-your-touchscreen-in-windows-10).

The procedure is:

- Run Device Manager
- Open Human Interface Devices
- Select the device "HID-compliant touch screen" (there may be more than one)
- Click *Action > Disable device*. For enabling, select *Enable device*.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the device through command line somehow? I was trying to create a batch file to enable and disable the device without having to go to device manager. Perhaps there's a way to access device manager from command line?

Comment: You could use `devcon` for that. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1501812/8672).